# Как добавить задержку в цикл while?

Tags: javascript

Есть цикл:

```
while (records.length && batchSize--) {
  getAjaxData(records.shift());
}
```

Но мне нужно чтобы он не подряд выполнял их мгновенно, а делал это с задержкой в 1 секунду? т.е чтобы 1 итерация = 1 секунда. Такое возможно?

Comment: @Grundy, и в каком месте это дубликат? Что даст мне повтор цикла на первой итерации?

Comment: суть в замене цикла, вызовом setTimeout

Comment: @Grundy, и как сделать в моем примере? 2 цикла чтоли?

Comment: циклы убираешь **совсем**. Смотришь как сделано в примере в ответе: есть функция, в которой вызывается setTimeout которому передается эта же сама функция. Вызывать setTimeout или нет определяется с помощью условия